# On looping through django allauth social login profile pictures

Tags: django, django-allauth, cookiecutter-django

I've been trying to loop through the social login account photos of the users and myself on the app that I'm doing. Currently, I have a different model for the contributors on the app that is shown on the homepage and on a separate page.

The models of my pages app is

```
class Volunteers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="volunteers/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "volunteer"
        verbose_name_plural = "volunteers"
```

The profile page has

```
{% if object == request.user %}
    ...
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img center-align" src="{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}">
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Since cookiecutter-django has a default users model, I imported the views of the model to my pages app to try and see if it will show on the home page.

The default cookiecutter-django model for the users is

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    # First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
    # around the globe.
    name = CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username})
```

The view on the pages app is

```
from pages.users.models import User

def home(request):
    ...
    users = User.objects.all()
    ...
    context = {"users": users }
    return render(request, pages/home.html, context)
```

The for loop on the template is

```
{% for u in users %}
    ...
    <img src="{{ u.user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{u.name}}">
    ...
{% endif %}
```

The console is showing the html templates but not the images.

Did I do anything wrong? Or how do I implement it properly?